# What is rss category format in manage dislay?

Tags: feeds

Anybody please explain what is the rss-category format, in the manage display settings of term referense field.

[image]

When I check this format, nothing is displayed on the node page.

Thanks.

Comment: check this may help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46009/how-to-make-drupal-7-render-taxonomy-tags-as-rss-categories

Comment: Thank you.I read this post, but I still not understand, where I can see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

This display setting hides taxonomy links on the node page and adds `category` elements into Drupal's RSS feed (http://example.com/rss.xml). Go to your site's RSS feed and you can see it in action.